# Implementing a for loop in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I have been trying to implement a for loop inside a recursive function using a for loop. Using the already implemented "for" in racket is not permitted. Is there a way to implement such a case?

Note : I am using an Intermediate Student Language for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example. The function `squares` produces a list of the first `n` square numbers. To produce that list, it loops over the number 0, ..., n-1 using an index `i`.

```
 (define (squares n)
    (define (loop i)
      (if (= i n)
          '()
          (cons (* i i) (loop (+ i 1)))))
    (loop 0))

 (squares 10)
```

Comment: When I use this code, I get an array as :  "define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part"

Comment: Derik if you are using a teaching language, you need to specify which one.

Comment: Wrap the inner definition in local. Lookup how to use local.

Comment: I am not allowed to use local as well.  I asked my professor

Comment: What are you allowed to use?

Comment: Just a list and functions included in a list like first, rest, etc. and conditional statements.

Comment: Were you asked to do a for loop? Or are you trying to solve a different problem? (I have a suspicion you are supposed to use recursion to solve list problems)

Comment: Yes. I am trying to make use of a for loop. I have to generate a list of lists, containing different permutations of a list of numbers

Comment: Have you made a list of test cases?

Comment: yes. (permute (list A B C)) = (list (list A B C)  (list A C B) (list B A C) (list B C A) (list C A B) (list C B A) (list A C B) )

Comment: Can you express (permute (list A B C)) in terms of A and (permute (list B C))?

Comment: I can, but I can't find a proper syntax in racket ISL to do so.

Comment: Can you describe it in words?

Comment: I am not used to functional programming. So I can't figure out a way or a syntax how can I achieve expressing  (permute (list A B C)) in terms of A  in racket

Comment: Take a look at https://see.stanford.edu/materials/icsppcs107/32-Scheme-Examples.pdf

Answer (score 2):

First off `for` in `#lang racket` is purely for side effects. Usually you would want the other variants like `for/map` and `for/fold` that ends up producing a value.

Racket is a descendant of Scheme and all looping in it is just syntactic sugar for a recursive function being applied. As an example the `do` loop:

```
(do ((vec (make-vector 5))
     (i 0 (+ i 1)))
    ((= i 5) vec)
  (vector-set! vec i i))                  
; ==>  #(0 1 2 3 4)
```

In reality the language doesn't have `do` as a primitive. Instead the implementation usually have a macro that makes it into this (or something similar):

```
(let loop ((vec (make-vector 5)) (i 0))
  (if (= i 5)
      vec
      (begin
        (vector-set! vec i i)
        (loop vec (+ i 1)))))
```

This is of course just sugar for this:

```
((letrec ((loop (lambda (vec i)  
                    (if (= i 5)
                        vec
                        (begin
                          (vector-set! vec i i)
                          (loop vec (+ i 1)))))))
   loop)
 (make-vector 5) (i 0))
```

And of course `letrec` is also sugar... It goes down to just using `lambda` at some level.